# Есть ли смысл делать метод synchronized, если он не использует глобальные переменные?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Предположим у меня несколько потоков. Все они с разными входными данными должны войти в метод

```
public int MyMeth(int x, int y){
... //какая-то реализация зависящая только от входных данных
return x*y;
}
```

Есть ли смысл (в многопоточной среде) делать такой метод **synchronized**, если он не использует никакие глобальные переменные, и не вызывает какие-либо функции, которые используют глобальные переменные?

Comment: Правильный на 93% - ответ который принят, но @Barmaley правильно заметил, что бывают ситуации когда мы можем проглядеть доступ к разделяемому ресурсу, к примеру, из библиотеки System. И тогда, похоже нужно синхронизировать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если под глобальными переменными подразумеваются в том числе и поля этого класса, а в качестве входных параметров используются только примитивные типы или константные объекты, то тогда `synchronized` не нужен.

Но в этом случае, чтобы избежать ненужных ошибок, лучше объявить метод статическим. В этом случае, при попытке обращения из метода к полям класса или другим нестатическим методам компилятор сразу сообщит об ошибке

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к тому, что не нужен synchronized. А можете пояснить что нам даст static? Я понимаю приблизительно, но начинающие - вряд ли. И я готов принять ваш ответ.

Comment: Я бы все равно добавил `synchronized` компилятор иногда может делать какие-то оптимизации, которые могут привести к неожиданностям.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin пояснил

Comment: @Barmaley Зачем? У synchronized две задачи: 1. обеспечить монопольный доступ к методу и сбросить кеш на входе и выходе из метода. Какую задачу ты хочешь решить добавлением?

Comment: Я всего лишь хочу обезопаситься он поведения компилятора, который в теории может решить завести некую "глобальную" переменную к которой получат доступ остальные потоки, что приведет к рассинхрону.

Comment: @Barmaley а можно какой-нибудь пример? Просто очевидно, что если класс не использует ничего извне и работает с аргументами-примитивами, то это вполне thread safe

Comment: @Barmaley вы человек с огромным опытом, можете дать свой развернутый ответ? Сообществу вопрос может показаться интересным.

Answer (score -2):

Я бы ратовал за явное указание `synchronized` каждый раз, проиллюстрирую примерами:

Очевидный пример thread-safe метода:

```
int myMethod1(int a, int b) {
   return (a+b);
}
```

Менее очевидный пример thread-safe метода:

```
int myMethod2(int a, int b) {
    int c = Math.power(a, b); //мы понимаем, что аппроксимация power() thread-safe
    return c;
}
```

Уже не thread-safe метод, используется разделяемый ресурс `System.in`

```
int myMethod3(int a, int b) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int c = scan.nextInt();
    return (a + b + c);
}
```

Пример метода с неизвестной thread-safety

```
int myMethod4(int a, int b) {
    int c = function(a, b); //метод function - является ли thread-safe - полезем в исходники?!
    return c;
}
```

Приведение примера выше к thread-safety

```
synchronized int myMethod4(int a, int b) {
    int c = function(a, b); 
    return c;
}
```

Мессидж мой в том, что метод иногда может быть сам по себе довольно сложным и чтобы не гадать на кофейной гуще, хотя бы с точки зрения улучшения читаемости кода лучше таки ставить `synchronized`

Comment: Очень хороший вариант ответа

Comment: Сомнительный совет. Во-первых, ставить synchronized "на всякий случай" может сильно навредить производительности. Во-вторых, если неизвестно, о гарантиях потокобезопасности `function`, то далеко не факт, что синхронизация на нашем объекте поможет сделать код потокобезопасным. А что если эта функция вызывается на другом объекте и все равно будет конфликт?

Comment: Потокобезопасность всегда дорого, тут уж ничего не поделаешь. Достаточно сравнить производительность `StringBuffer` и `StringBuilder` (оба делают одно и то же, но один thread-safe, второй - нет (различие скоростей на порядок).

Comment: Про дорого я не спорю. Я о другом. Без знания почему `function` не потокобезопасная, добавление `synchronized` на метод нашего класса, может дать ложное чувство безопасности. Проблему не решит, а цену за синхронизацию мы заплатим. Т.е. все равно нужно разбираться в `function`.

Comment: @RomanKonoval ну вы заминусовали. Мне кажется человек тоже важные нюансы описал, даже не удобно перед ним. Хотелось бы чтобы данная версия тоже не была удалена, потому что доступ к разделяемому ресурсу - всегда можно проглядеть. А потом ищи - свищи, что не так.

Comment: @Barmaley не удаляйте пожалуйста свою версию. Тут тот случай, когда заминусовали в общем-то дельную информацию.

Comment: Я не минусовал. Ответ содержит полезную информацию в общем, но в нем есть и опасный совет.

Comment: @AndrewKachalin я почти никогда не удаляю свои посты (почти). Пусть будет, дискуссия всегда полезна. Здесь много "специалистов", которым проще заминусовать, чем поправить ошибку. Вообще ответ был не о правильности кода, а в попытке иллюстрации чем чревата ложная безопасность (согласен, иллюстрация получилась не очень удачной).